# Does the pizzicato apply to the 2nd Violins or the Violas?

Tags: orchestral-strings, pizzicato

In the 69th bar of the 1st movement of Tchaikovsky's Symphony No. 1, it says for an instrument to be played in pizzicato, but I'm not sure which one.

[image: Three staves with "pizz." marking between the middle and lower stave.]

The top instrument is the 1st Violins, middle is the 2nd Violins, and bottom is the Violas.

Answer (score 3):

The *pizzicato* marking refers to the second violins. Here's the same passage in a different edition:
[image]

Comment: Is there any way to tell that from the edition shown in the question, or it is inherently ambiguous there?

Comment: @gidds In the example from the question the marking is much closer to the second violins than to the violas and also closer than the dynamic (dynamics go under the system), so not ambiguous.